# Getting "Null pointer exception" at the time of executing maven project using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When my code is executing first it execute the `LoginTest.Java` class after that it goes to the `Main.Java` but in these I get the null pointer exception, its not reading get the driver in method.
Can anyone please help me to resolve, I am beginner in this.

Thanks in advance..!!

**LoginTest.Java class**:

```
public class LoginTest {
    private static final String ADDRESS_TO_TEST = "http://www.gmail.com";

    private WebDriver driver;
    Main Login;
    HomePage homePage;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {

        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(ADDRESS_TO_TEST);

    }

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void testLoginPageAppear() {

        // Create Login Page object
        Login = new Main(driver);
        System.out.println("Login-->" + Login);
        Login.loginToGmail("abc@gmail.com", "abc");
        homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        // Verify home page
        Assert.assertTrue(homePage.getHOmePageEmailAddress().toLowerCase()
                .contains("Google Account: abc@gmail.com"));
    }
}
```

**Main.Java Class:**

```
package GmailLogin;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Main {

    /*
     * Reference
     * URL:http://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-
     * selenium-ultimate-guide.html
     */

    WebDriver driver;

    By email = By.id("Email");
    By nextButton = By.id("next");
    By password = By.id("Passwd");
    By signInButton = By.id("signIn");

    public Main(WebDriver driver) {
        System.out.println("Driver--->" + driver);
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String strEmailAddress) {
        driver.findElement(email).sendKeys(strEmailAddress);

    }

    public void clickNextButton() {
        driver.findElement(nextButton).click();
    }

    public void setPassword(String strPassword) {
        driver.findElement(password).sendKeys(strPassword);
    }

    public void clickSignInButton() {
        driver.findElement(signInButton).click();
    }

    public void loginToGmail(String strEmailAddress, String strPassword) {

        System.out.println("Email-->" + strEmailAddress);
        System.out.println("Password-->" + strPassword);
        this.setEmailAddress(strEmailAddress);
        this.clickNextButton();
        this.setPassword(strPassword);
        this.clickSignInButton();
    }
}
```

**Null pointer exception:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Driver--->null
Login-->GmailLogin.Main@5940ce27
Email-->abc@gmail.com
Password-->abc
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 21.016 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
testLoginPageAppear(GmailLogin.LoginTest)  Time elapsed: 0.047 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GmailLogin.LoginTest.testLoginPageAppear(LoginTest.java:47)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line causes your driver object to be in method scope only:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Change it to

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

To fill your class attribute instead.